# I need to sort an array in excel following the order of another one

Tags: excel, sorting

Hello everyone and thanks a lot in advance for any help.

I'm not very good using Excel. I want to know if there is a simple way in which I can sort a small two-column data matrix following the order of a column that contains all the bird species in Colombia. I study birds and I usually do avifauna characterization studies. I've always had this problem of not being able to order efficiently using the taxonomic order of species. I have always done it by hand and it takes me a really long time.

This is the file with the example that ilustrates my problem: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1089VD4ylJiW9Xw9xRFI0ehraAc_t-qSa/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=112790797352647984659&rtpof=true&sd=true

There are two worksheets in this file. One called "Species" and the other "Data". I need to know if it is possible to make Data array can be sorted following the Species column.

I have tried creating custom lists and the number of entries to create a certain order does not allow me to put more than 100. I have also tried using commands Sort and Sortby without any success.

Again, thanks a lot for any help.

Regrets.

Comment: The way I understand your issue: in your species table create a new column with a number starting from 1 (you can use the SEQUENCE to do it “automatically”). Then you can use XLOOKUP in your data table to get this number from Species table referring to the species name. Then you can sort the data table according to the order of the numbers

Comment: Another solution is you just add another column in the species table with XLOOKUP the abundance from the data table by matching the species name.

Comment: Actually, with the MATCH as proposed by Ron you will save a step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Data worksheet, add a helper column:

```
C2: =MATCH(A2,Species!$A$1:$A$2000,0)
```

and fill down.

Then Sort by the helper column